# Use variables on MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My basic MongoDB query

```
test.find({$or : [{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:57"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:58"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:59"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:00"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:01"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:02"},]})
```

I want use variables for replace expression and I tried

```
    //console.log(expression);
    test.find({"$or" : [expression]  }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
});
```

But got a error

```
MongoError: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects
```

With variables `expression` are `{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:57"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:58"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:59"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:00"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:01"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:02"},`

How I can use variables on MongoDB query?

Comment: A variable can only have one value. What is expression really?

Comment: I understand your question.
`variables expression` is `StringBuilder.toString();`

Comment: And what is StringBuilder?

Comment: I use `StringBuilder` to build a string with those `expression` above.

Comment: Cool. Again: What should that be?

Answer (score 1):

`$or` and `$and` always need `array` of expressions.

```
var expression = [{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:57"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:58"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 11:59"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:00"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:01"},{"timeIn":"2018-1-31 12:02"}]

db.test.find({"$or" : expression  }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0})
```